# How to use BloomFilter with Redis

Tags: redis

I met an issue about Redis Penatration.  Too many meaningless query from the clients go to the database because no keys are matched in Redis.
Now I hope to use a BloomFilter to filter some meaningless  query, but I don't know how to use it with Redis or DB.
A bunch of questions are listed below.

When will the key be added in Bloom Filter ?  just before the key is added in Redis cache ?
Are Keys in Bloom Filter deleted if the key in Redis expires?

or read all the keys from Database and put them in Blomm filter?
but if the key is deleted from DB,  can we delete the key from BloomFilter?

Really appreicate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to avoid cache penetration

Your best strategy of course would be to implement some logic (e.g., IP range filtering) before checking the cache.

On top of this, if the same unacceptable addresses are queried repeatedly, you may consider storing these addresses in Redis with an empty string value.

If you need to store millions of invalid keys, indeed, you may consider using a Bloom filter.

RedisBloom is a Redis module, developed by Redis Inc., that adds probabilistic data structures (including a Bloom filter) to Redis. You can install RedisBloom on top of an existing Redis, or switch to [Redis Stack](https://redis.io/docs/stack/), which includes RedisBloom to start with.

RedisBloom commands are documented [here](https://redis.io/commands/?group=bf).

Simply create a Bloom filter using BF.RESERVE and add invalid addresses using BF.ADD. To determine if an invalid address has been seen before, use BF.EXISTS (the answer "1" means that, with high probability, the value has been seen before, and a "0" means that it definitely wasn't seen before).

> How to handle incoming requests

Since false positive matches are possible with a Bloom Filter (BF), you have several options:

1. Store all valid keys in a BF upfront

   - Add all valid keys to the BF
   - When a request is received, search in the Bloom filter.
   - If found in the BF - it is, with high probability, a valid key. Try to fetch it from the DB. If not found in the DB (low probability) it was a false positive.
   - If not found in the BF: it is necessarily an invalid key.
2. Store valid keys in a BF on-the-fly

   - When a request is received, search in the Bloom filter.
   - If found in the BF - it is, with high probability, a valid key that was already seen. Try to fetch it from the DB. If not found in the DB (low probability) it was a false positive.
   - If not found in the BF - it is either a first-time valid key or an invalid key. Check, and if valid - add to the BF.
3. Store invalid keys in a BF

   - When a request is received, search in the Bloom filter.
   - If found in the BF - it is, with high probability, an invalid key. Note that it may be a valid key (low probability) and you will ignore it, but that's a price you should be ready to pay if you go this way.
   - If not found in the BF - it is either a valid key or a first-time invalid key. Check, and if invalid - add to the BF.

Some notes:

- You don't need to add an item to a BF more than once (there is no benefit, but also no harm).
- You cannot delete keys from a BF, but you can use a [Cuckoo filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_filter) instead, which supports deletions (but has some disadvantages compared to BF). [RedisBloom supports Cuckoo filters as well](https://redis.io/commands/?group=cf).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
The problem is  the Keys  from the client are random things,  it is not easy to figure out what they are.  for example,  the client uses IP address as one part of the key.  IP address has a wide range.   
all the acceptable IP address are saved in DB, I use Redis as the cache to improve the query speed, but  some random IP address which are not saved in DB  causes the Redis cache penetration.  so how to solve this issue ?  Thanks.

Comment: @Jason, ok, now I understand. Rewrote my answer.

Comment: It is very informative , Thanks Lior. 
Let me rephase it:
1. when the client request comes,  if it is not available in Reidis/DB,  put this invaild IP address into Bloom Filter 
2. when the new request comes,  check the Bloom filter first. If it is in the filter, then SKip this invalid IP.   if it is not,   go to Redis/DB.   if not available  there , put it into Bloom Filter again 
3. repeat  step 2 ..... 

Is that process correct ?   Thanks.

Comment: @Jason I added more information